# Can one tie a bridge link state to one member interface state?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

Is it possible to tie the state of a bridge's link to that of a member interface's link state?

Scenario: Virtualization host plugged directly into a SOHO router. Router needs to be rebooted. Because a bridge's state, by default, remains UP unless all members are DOWN, VMs on the host don't initiate DHCP back to the router since as far as they're concerned nothing happened to their network link.

In this case it would be ideal to be able to tie the state of the bridge link to that of the physical interface connecting it to the router so that VMs would experience a link DOWN event.

Comment: There is no built-in facility to do that. Maybe you can write a script that does what you want (by monitoring the link state of the target interface and running the appropriate commands to bring other links down then up)?

Comment: Btw: the VM won't react to the bridge going down then up. It would react to its dedicated TAP interface (which is set as bridge port when the VM is started) going down then up.